# The method getAllCellInfo() is undefined for the type TelephonyManager [Android]

Tags: android, eclipse, undefined, telephonymanager, cellinfo

Using the following code, I'm trying to get the available cell information:

```
import android.telephony.CellInfo;

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService( context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );
List<CellInfo> cellList = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
```

Knowing that the method getAllCellInfo() and class CellInfo was introduced in API Level 17, I've set **android:minSdkVersion="17"** in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

However, in Eclipse I'm getting an errors stating:
*The import android.telephony.CellInfo cannot be resolved* and
*The method getAllCellInfo() is undefined for the type TelephonyManager*

I've tried cleaning, closing Eclipse and rebuilding my project, but I'm still getting these errors. I'm at a loss as to why Eclipse is not recognizing these declarations

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** Permission **android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** is also included within the AndroidManifest.xml file. But the issue still remains.

Comment: Have you added the permission `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: Yes, that is also in the Manifest. I'm able to use method telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator(); which requires that permission.

Comment: **Solved:**  The issue was, even though I did edit the AndroidManifest.xml file.  the **project.properties** file was not being updated, changing: `target=android-17` in the file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `project.properties` file and look at the target you are building against.  It should look something like this:

`target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:17`

This is an old project I had on hand which was building for API 17 (with Google APIs.)

You can also go into the Project properties and check the target in the UI.  That setting corresponds to this file and is what Eclipse uses to build against, not the manifest.  The manifest is used at runtime on the platform to know what compatibility modes to enable in the framework.

Comment: Yes, that was what the issue was.  Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome.  I'll toss this out there for you: if you use Android Studio, it'll actually tell you not to put the min/target SDK info in the manifest file.  It uses the gradle build files to know what to build against and will autogenerate that section of your manifest for you.  Helps to reduce this type of strangeness.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'm currently on a project where it's not feasible to switch over to Android Studio.  Too much involved in build and deployment process and too close to deadlines to switch over now.